# What is the best place to put a feature request?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if you would like to have feature requests posted in Stack Exchange.

For example, I searched for a feature request in SE to mass delete entries in the back end. There are several questions discussing it but, there isn't a question that is specifically a feature request for this functionality.

How should I post these when they come up?

Thanks

Comment: Feature requests should be submitted directly to Pixel & Tonic. They are not something to post to StackExchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a ["Feedback and Ideas"](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/106505340287442511226/stream/3ff4ba0f-25e6-4f6f-ad4b-04da3a7e81c9) section on Craft's Google+ site, if you'd like to give others a chance to discuss your idea (a "+Brandon" etc. is probably not necessary, I experienced that P+T reads all feedback posted there).

Or you address your feedback directly to P+T's email support: [support@buildwithcraft.com](http://buildwithcraft.com/help)

Comment: This answer seems outdated, check the answer of Bonk below.

Answer (score 5):

The new [Github Repo](https://github.com/craftcms/cms) is now the official place to file bugs and feature requests. From the [Craft 3 beta announcement](https://craftcms.com/news/craft-3-beta):

> Going forward, this is the place to file bugs and feature requests,
>   even for Craft 2.

Answer (score 3):

Craft now has a official feedback website with feature voting:

http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests

Comment: Now deprecated I think?